# How to programmatically create UIView with this setup?

Tags: uiview, autoresizingmask

I'd like to create a UIView programmatically with the exact equivalent of this setup in IB (see screenshot).

Whatever I have attempted myself would not behave the same when rotating and autoresizing the view, so I need a sample from an expert.

[image: UIView in IB]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example:

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[customView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Comment: Thanks. Though it seems for that particular diagram only flexible width and flexible height is needed as explained here: http://bit.ly/w5MaUx

Answer (score 13):

Swift 2.0:

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

Swift 3.0:

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
```

Comment: Swift 2.2 as well.

Comment: Added Swift 3 version.

Comment: Thanks, @LinusG. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  View.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin,.FlexibleWidth,.FlexibleHeight,.FlexibleTopMargin]
```